# How to inspect Module#initialize?

Tags: methods, initialization, ruby-1.9.3

I have defined a module Vehicle such that

```
module Vehicle
  def initialize(make, model)
  end

  def start
  end

  def stop
  end
end
```

I want to inspect the instance methods defined in Vehicle using Module#instance_methods and Module#instance_method like

```
Vehicle.instance_methods.each do |method|
  Vehicle.instance_method(method).parameters
end
```

The problem is Vehicle#instance_methods only returns [:start, :stop]. How do I inspect the initialize method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`initialize` doesn't show up in the list of public instance methods since it's private:

```
>> Vehicle.instance_methods
=> ["start", "stop"]
>> Vehicle.private_instance_methods
=> ["initialize"]
```

So, you can just do

```
Vehicle.instance_method("initialize").parameters
```